# DevDemon 4.0.0 Tagger tags not saving when publishing

Tags: ee3, upgrade, devdemon-tagger

I upgraded from EE2 to EE3. I had Devdemon tagger add-on, so I also had to upgrade it to the newest version (4.0.0) in order to be compatible with EE3.

The problem is that whenever I add a tag to an entry (new or existing) it doesn't get saved. When I hit Publish it seems like it is there, but when I go back to the entry the added tag isn't there.  So in the front end there are no tags showing.

The entries added before I did the EE upgrade DO have their corresponding tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enable the EE3 Caching Driver under Settings->Debugging & Output.  That was my issue.